# A good flash automation solution

Tags: flash, apache-flex, automation, automated-tests

I'm looking for a good solution to automate testing of a website, major parts of which are in flash/flex.

The preferred language is c#, but I wouldn't mind java, python or php if the solution on any of those languages is better (meaning, easier to write on, less bugs and more tutorials and samples).

What is the best framework around for flash automation in my case?

Comment: You might want to look at FlexMonkey (http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey).  I'm not sure if it works with Flash.

Answer (score 1):

[FlexMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey) is one option, as Amy suggested. I'm not sure if it works w/ Flash Pro or non-Flex Stuff, though.

[QTP](http://mercuryquicktestprofessional.blogspot.com/2007/10/does-quicktest-professional-support.html) is another option.

[RIATest](http://www.riatest.com/) is a third option.

I'm not sure the extent of non-Flex support of any of these, though.

Answer (score 1):

For UI automation,
Adobe UI scripter
http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki2/FAQ/